# Why jCanvas draws wrong pixels?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, jcanvas

I have an object of pixel map, each row contains an object of columns, that contains a colour information. Then I choose the colour using `switch()`, and then I simply draw it to canvas. Here is the code:

```
  for(var pixX in pixmap) {
    for(var pixY in pixmap[pixX]) {
      switch(pixmap[pixX][pixY]) {
        case 1: var pixColor='lightgray'; break;
        case 2: var pixColor='black'; break;
        default: var pixColor='forestgreen'; break;
        }
      $('canvas#surface').drawRect({
        fillStyle: pixColor,
        width: 1, height: 1,
        x: pixX, y: pixY,
        fromCenter: false
        });
      }
    }
```

It draws the pixels, but the pixel position is somehow zoomed, although, the pixels are really just 1px big. I can't determine, how much it zooms. When I draw after a while to the canvas, the position is correct. What's the problem?

**Edit:** I've recreated it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qyNTn/

Comment: Recreate in jsFiddle, so that we can understand better the problem

Comment: What are you trying to do? i don't understand, in your fiddle you just create 6 dots size of 2px

Comment: Maybe you ought to read jCanvas API docs... http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/

Comment: In real code the pixel map comes via ajax from mysql, but the problem is same - the dot position is zoomed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the `pixX` and `pixY` variables are converted to strings by JavaScript. You need to convert `pixX` and `pixY` to numbers before passing them to jCanvas.

The reason being is because JavaScript stores each key name (for any object) as a string. Therefore, when you iterate through an object using a `for in` loop, the key name will always be a string. In other words,  `pixX` and `pixY` are treated as strings, so you need to convert them to numbers using a function such as `parseFloat`.

In addition, jCanvas performs many numerical calculations when drawing shapes, so it always prefers a number over a string for any numerical value.

Anyway, fixing your code (to produce the expected behavior) only requires a single change to your `drawRect()` parameters.

```
x: parseFloat(pixX), y: parseFloat(pixY),
```